# Unable to locate element / Cant find element

Tags: c#, selenium

Hey person reading this,
i am struggling with selenium and cant not find any solution even though i found threads about same issues.

I am trying to access a specific element but somehow cant get it working.

Site is loaded and i can access other parts via CssSelector and id XPath somehow doesnt work.
But the specific part i want to access cant be accessed somehow even if its fully visible and shown when i inspect elements myself.

Already tried with timer and i even checked if i can find it in inspect element before the program does...

To get the CssSelector or XPath i used inbuild function from Firefox and Chrome

```
IWebElement elementpart = driver.FindElement(By.Id("frameContent"));
```

Thats what i try and driver is obv the webDriver

and i try to access

```
<div id="frameContent">
```

If you need more information just write here.. I just can't find any solution...

When i try to use wait method on frameContent it never finds it even though i can see its there..

Thankx for trying to help

**UPDATE**

```
<iframe id="ContentFrame" style="height: 493px;"></iframe>
```

its a item of the above iframe

Comment: Make sure, the element is not placed in <iframe>. Otherwise, you have to switch to frame https://riptutorial.com/selenium-webdriver/example/17365/switch-to-a-frame-using-csharp

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML of the element including the HTML of the `<iframe>` incase the element is within an _iframe_

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Max Daroshchanka,
I got it working thanks to your comment :D

> Make sure, the element is not placed in . Otherwise, you have to switch to frame https://riptutorial.com/selenium-webdriver/example/17365/switch-to-a-frame-using-csharp